# Is there a way I can skip the username of a file path in python

Tags: python

I'm working with `shutil` and I would like to know if there is a way I could skip past the user file? For example `C:\Users\bob\test` , is there a way I can skip past the bob folder and go straight to the test folder?

Comment: On Linux, there's **~**. On Windows, maybe use the os library.

Comment: What have you tried? What does your code look like?

Comment: What do you  mean by `skip past`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
import os
file_path = 'c:/users/' + os.getlogin()
```

os is a built in module. The os.getlogin() function returns the name of the currently logged in user, which is the same as the file name for the currently logged in user. Hoped this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but if you put your .py file in the folder you want to access (in this case `test`, you can do `./fileyouwant.png`, instead of `C:\Users\bob\test\fileyouwant.png`.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, shutil is using  [pathlib objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) , you can use absolute path (on windows, as it seems to be your case, absolute path start from the drive (c:) and follows the full tree directory to the file itself. you can also use a relative path, depends on where you execute your python code.

For example, if you execute your python code from c:\Users\bob directory you can access the files throught .\test\filename

regards